# Trying to populate an array from a text file, but needs to be inclusive (0-100)

Tags: java, file-io

I've made a program that takes the input (scores) from a file and outputs all of the scores, along with the average, highest, and lowest scores. However, I am struggling to exclude the scores that are not within the 0-100 bounds (exclude meaning print to the monitor and not the actual output file), which also messes with the results I'm getting. The if/else condition I have does not seem to do anything at all. Here are my variables, along with the loop I have to populate my array. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
   int sum = 0; // sum of the grades
   double avg; // avg of the grades (change to mean later)
   final int SIZE = 23; // size of the array
   int[] scores = new int[SIZE]; // array to store the scores
   int i = 0; // array subscript
   int high = 0; // variable to hold the high grade
   int low = 0; // variable to hold the low grade


  // Read the input and write the output

  out.printf("The scores are: ");

  while (in.hasNextInt())
  {
     // statements to input the scores, output the scores, accumulate the 
     sum, and modify the subscript
     if (i >= 0 && i <= 100)
     {
       scores[i] = in.nextInt();
       sum = sum + scores[i];
       out.print(scores[i]);
       i++;
     }
     else
     {
       System.out.println("The ignored scores are: " + scores[i]);
     }  

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing your index with the value entered

change your code to something like

```
while (in.hasNextInt())
{
 // statements to input the scores, output the scores, accumulate the 
 int input = in.nextInt();
 if (input >= 0 && input <= 100)
 {
   scores[i] = input;
   sum = sum + scores[i];
   out.print(scores[i]);
   i++;
 }
 else
 {
   System.out.println("The ignored score is: " + input);
 }  

}
```

Comment: Hm, still seems to be printing the same thing in the output file. I'll just keep at it, thank you though!

Comment: OKAY, I've got it now after some messing around. Just changed the "i" to "input" in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

The code should check score, not the array index i

```
while (in.hasNextInt())
{
 // statements to input the scores, output the scores, accumulate the 
 sum, and modify the subscript
 int score = in.nextInt()
 if (score >= 0 && score <= 100)
 {
   scores[i] = score;
   sum = sum + scores[i];
   out.print(scores[i]);
   i++;
 }
 else
 {
   System.out.println("The ignored scores are: " + score);
 }  
}
```